# How to find the delta for the following problem?

Tags: epsilon-delta

Let $f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2x^4y-5x^2y^2+y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \ (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\ 0, \qquad \qquad \qquad (x, y) = (0,0 ) \end{cases}$. Find a $\delta > 0$  such that $|f(x, y)-f(0, 0)| < 0.1$ whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$.

Use polar coordinates: $$x=r\cos\theta, \qquad
 y=r\sin\theta$$ where it is given that $r < \delta$. 
Then the  expression $f(r,\theta)$  becomes $$|f(x, y)-f(0, 0)| = |2r\cos^4 \theta\sin \theta +r\sin^5\theta
-5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta| < 0.01$$ implies that 
$$-0.01 < 2r\cos^4 \theta\sin \theta +r\sin^5\theta
-5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta < 0.01$$ $$ \implies 5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta-0.01 < 2r\cos^4 \theta\sin \theta +r\sin^5\theta < 5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+0.01$$ $$ \implies \frac{5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta-0.01}{2\cos^4 \theta\sin \theta +\sin^5\theta} < r < \frac{5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+0.01}{2\cos^4 \theta\sin \theta +\sin^5\theta}$$ where denominator is not $0$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: Are you sure that the middle term, $-5x^2y^2$, is correct? I think the powers of $x$ and $y$ should add up to more than $4$, otherwise the limit does not exist

Comment: Yes you are correct. Actually this is a misprint in the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Andrei see the edited post please.

Comment: No. It is not possible. Choose $x=y$ or $\cos\theta=\sin\theta=\sqrt{2}/2$ For small $r$ you can neglect those terms, but the term without $r$ will be $5/4$

Comment: Actually $r$ can be big also. So such a $\delta$ exists in this case,

Comment: You need to find a solution for *any* $r<\delta$. So if you find a solution for big $r$, it is not valid if it does not work for smaller $r$.

Comment: @Andrei Please see the edited post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85047/discussion-between-andrei-and-mittal-g).

Answer (score 1):

If all the powers of $x$ and $y$ in the numerator add up to $5$, use polar coordinates: $$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$$
Then you have an expression $f(r,\theta)=r g(\theta)$, where $g$ is a simple function. You can maximize it by taking both $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ to be $1$ (or $0$ or $-1$ if you need to subtract). Say if middle term is $-5x^3y^2$, I would use $g(\theta)<2\cdot1^4\cdot1+5\cdot1^3\cdot1^2+1^5=8$. The you have $f(r,\theta)<8r$. Now putting the condition $8r<0.1$ yields your desired $r$.

Comment: What is the sum of power is not $5$. Then it might be possible that even as the limit does not exist, but some $\delta > 0$ exists.

Comment: If the sum is $4$ you can ignore the other terms and you get $-5\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$, independent of $r$, for small enough $r$. That small enough you can also get using the same approach.